# What is the default sort order in the Find Printers dialog?

Tags: windows-xp, printing

Within the Find Printers dialog, if a user clicks the Find Now button, all available printers on the network are shown. The printers seem to appear in a somewhat random order though where I'd expect them to be sorted by name (or something) by default. What determines the default sort order?

Comment: Sorry, don't know the answer of this, however I wonder if the default sort-order has something to do with the _hostname_ of the printer in question and not what you've named it, in AD.

Comment: I can tell you that the sort order in the "Find Printers..." dialog in Windows Server 2003 isn't the same as the sort order returned from an LDAP query against the root of the domain searching for (objectClass=printQueue). It's not sorted by objectGUID either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are appearing randomly, it is likely sorted by which printer responds first to the request.

Answer (score 0):

They appear randomly, but you may sort them alphabetically via the context menu. Anyway please watch out that you may do this ordering independently in menu view or in in explorer view.